# Python, sqlite3 and UPDATE several rows

Tags: python, sqlite, set

Here is the code that I am trying to execute

```
db.execute('''UPDATE WARDWINS \
    SET map = ?, 
    SET team1wards = ?, 
    SET team2wards = ?, 
    SET mostwards = ?, 
    SET winningteam = ?, 
    SET mostwardswin = ? 
    where matchID = ?''', (dic['mapID'][0], dic['team1wards'], dic['team2wards'], dic['mostwards'], dic['winningteam'], dic['wardswins'], match))
```

What I want to achieve is to have a single execute command update all the above rows at the same time, but for some reason I cannot seem to figure out how to do just that. I get the following error message:

```
>>> dic['mostwards'], dic['winningteam'], dic['wardswins'], match))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "SET": syntax error
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, the answer was nearly correct. (Isn't it always?)
The sqlite3.execute command requires one SET only, and the others were redundant, and created a syntax error. The right way of doing it is as follows:

```
db.execute('''UPDATE WARDWINS \
    SET map = ?, 
    team1wards = ?, 
    team2wards = ?, 
    mostwards = ?, 
    winningteam = ?, 
    mostwardswin = ? 
    where matchID = ?''', (dic['mapID'][0], dic['team1wards'], dic['team2wards'], dic['mostwards'], dic['winningteam'], dic['wardswins'], match))
```